# Copy object to another object java

Tags: java

I have an object A that contains for example:

```
class A{
    String elem1;
    Int elem2;
    ...get and set 
}
```

and i have a class B that contains same element and name of field:

```
class B{
    String elem1;
    Int elem2;
    ...get and set 
}
```

i want copy class A value into class B value without modify the class. 
How can solve? thanks.

Comment: Without modifying which class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394978/copy-fields-between-similar-classes-in-java

Comment: Why would you need such a thing. Just make the class implement cloneable and clone it to make new objects.

Comment: @AniketThakur I believe the OP wants to create an instance of a different class, with the same properties. In this case cloning the object isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

There's no "clean" way to do this; you will need to manually copy every entry.

```
A a = ...;
B copy = new B();
copy.elem1 = a.elem1;
copy.elem2 = a.elem2;
```

Alternatively, you could use reflection, but it's performance costly and somewhat unclear, and will fail if there is any inconsistencies between the classes' field definitions.

```
A a = ...;
B copy = new B();
for (Field field : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Field copyField = copy.getClass().getDeclaredField(field.getName());
    field.setAccessible(true);
    copyField.setAccessible(true);
    if (!field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
        Object value = field.get(a);
        field.set(copy, value);
    } else if (field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
        int value = field.getInt(a);
        field.setInt(copy, value);
    } else if { ... } // and so forth
}
```

Comment: copy.elem1 = a.elem1; Seriously? Variables in most cases are private(it's a good programming practice) and you must use getters/setters. And again is reflection answer to everything?

Comment: getters and setters are only provided for publicly available information. If you are doing a true copy then you probably want the non-public information also. Reflection the answer for everything - no, but it is the right answer here.

Comment: @AniketThakur In the question, the classes do not have getters or setters.  It would be simple to modify those two lines of code to use getters and setters anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this simple way

```
 firstObj.setElem1 (secObj.getElem1());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a third class which would act as a factory, with a method taking an instance of `A` as a parameter, and returning an instance of `B`.

```
public final class MyFactory
    {
    public static B createBFromA (A instance)
        {
        B newInstance = new B ();
        newInstance.setXXX (instance.getXXX ());
        return newInstance;
        }
    }
```

The advantage of using an external factory is to isolate the code that creates your `B` instances from the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never but here is the answer I have found. You can use GSON to serialize the Object to String and then deserialize to the class B. Here is the tested example:

```
package JSON.test.obj_copy;
public class TestClassA {

    private String field1 = "pikachu";
    private Integer field2 = 1;
    private List<String> field3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    private Obj field4 = new Obj();

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new StringBuilder("field1: " + field1 + "\n")
                .append("field2: " + field2 + "\n")
                .append("field3: " + field3 + "\n")
                .append("field4: " + field4)
                .toString();
    }
}

public class TestClassB {

    private String field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private List<String> field3;
    private Obj field4;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new StringBuilder("field1: " + field1 + "\n")
                .append("field2: " + field2 + "\n")
                .append("field3: " + field3 + "\n")
                .append("field4: " + field4)
                .toString();
    }
}

public class Obj {
}

public class MainObjCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TestClassA a = new TestClassA();
        TestClassB b;
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String s1 = g.toJson(a);
        b = g.fromJson(s1, TestClassB.class);

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
field1: pikachu
field2: 1
field3: [A, B, C]
field4: JSON.test.obj_copy.Obj@22d8cfe0
```