# Create new object by parent class

Tags: java, subclass

I have an example.

class `Candidate` is superclass and `ExperienceCandidate` is subclass.

i have 2 type to create object is:

`ExperienceCandidate temp = new ExperienceCandidate();`

`Candidate temp = new ExperienceCandidate();`

Help me distinguish the differences between these two constructs and which one is used in which case

Comment: Have you googled at all? Read through this Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924974/create-instance-from-superclass-instance as well as this article - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java-4th/9781449372477/ch06s01.html

Comment: this looks like a homework question, but the term you are looking for is "Polymorphism"

Answer (score 0):

Generally whenever you are creating an object , it is just to create an instance of the class so that you can use it somewhere. In the case of Superclasses and Subclasses , whenever you initiaze a subclass of a class , it already contains all the objects/methods of the superclass. In your case , there are two logical discrepancies :

- The `Candidate temp = new ExperienceCandidate();` is not the correct way to call an object , the correct way to call the object of the superclass is `Candidate temp = new Candidate();`
- There is almost no use creating the object of candidate class to use in your superclass as you can just use the keyword `super()` to call the constuctor of the superclass and anyway all the function of the superclass are available for you to use in the subclass (since you extended to it)