# How to associate a subclass Object with a superclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question on how I can create a new object and associate it with another already initialized object from its parent class in java.

To be clearer, I have a superclass `Profile`, then a subclass `Contract` which extends `Profile` and then two other subclasses `HomePhone` and `MobilePhone` that both extend `Contract`.

Two of the options of my menu are:

1. New profile.
2. New contract(HomePhone or MobilePhone contract).

Suppose that the user has already created a profile without a contract and has entered some personal information. I initialize a `Profile` object and then i store it to an `ArrayList`.

```
Profile p = new Profile();
/*
Promt the user to enter his information
and when he has finished add the object to the array list.
*/ 
profiles.add(p);
```

I'm okay until here.

Next suppose that a user who has already a profile (which is already stored in the `ArrayList`), decides to press 2 to buy a new contract.

I think that the most appropriate manner to do this is :

```
Profile c = new MobilePhone();
```

But I will not have access to the appropriate user's profile in that way.

So I wonder how could I implement it. All I want is to associate the new contract with an already existed profile based on an id of the user.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: Can you not do new MobilePhone(existingProfile), in turn, call the constructor chain and initialize a profile using the existing profile?

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create instance from superclass instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924974/create-instance-from-superclass-instance)

Comment: That was a good help, but not exactly what im looking for. Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Read about Java Creational design pattern for best practices. https://www.baeldung.com/creational-design-patterns

```
public class Parent {
    private String parentProperty;

    public Parent(final String parentProperty) {
        this.parentProperty = parentProperty;
    }
//getter and setters
}


public class Child extends Parent {
    private String childProperty;

    public Child(final String parentProperty, final String childProperty) {
        super(parentProperty);
        this.childProperty = childProperty;
    }
    public Child(Parent p, final String childProperty) {
        super(p.getparentProperty());
        this.childProperty = childProperty;
    }
//getter and setters
}
```