# getDeclaredFields() of a Hibernate Lazy loading object does not return fields

Tags: java, reflection

I fetch an object using reflection as following. Here the field I fetched is mapped by hibernate Lazy loading.

```
final Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
Object obj = field.get(instance);
```

Then I use the resulting object as follows

```
obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()
```

But this does not return me all the fields which is defined in the Object. This Object can be any of the entity in my JPA entities list. I believe there is a problem with using Object instead of casted object.

How can I do this, and get all the fields of this new found object.

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted this. But I would like to know the explanation. May be i can provide more info.. For more clarity I dont know what type it should be casted into. The class  type is there in field but its dynamic

Comment: Are you looking for a declared field on a superclass instead of one on the current actual class? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16966699/504685

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (And no, this will have nothing to do with casting.)

Comment: Give us a sample that we can reproduce. In your code you'll find that `obj.getClass()` does *not* refer to `Object` but it will indeed have the type of the field.

Comment: i added explenation of what i'm trying to do

Comment: You're just repeating yourself and ignoring our request. Show the actual code, not an explanation of what you want your code to do.

Comment: ok. code is added too'

Comment: Seems like my question is still unclear for people. Thank you for the time

Comment: Are you sure the field you are looking for exists on the actual class of the object and not a superclass? Have you inspected with a debugger that the object you're calling getDeclaredFields on is not in fact a generated surrogate that extends the class where the field you think should exist is actually declared?

Comment: Ok. i found the problem. The object fetched is pointing to Hibernate reference. not to the actual object because that field is a mapped with Lazy fetch. Thankx all

Comment: A lesson to learn the hard way: using reflection or the instanceof operator in combination with Hibernate entities is not a reliable thing to do as you may just run into a proxy class. I felt lots of pain in that area until I discovered this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem simply is Reflection and Hibernate does not work with easy steps.

the `instance` object in code is a fetched object by hibernate (Lazy loading). That Object does not return a real java object, but a hibernate proxy object. Calling Reflection on proxy object will give totally unexpected results than what you looking for.

In comments https://stackoverflow.com/users/424903/gimby pointed to a solution which can be used to un-proxy the hibernate lazy loaded object.  [Converting Hibernate proxy to real object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object)