# How get fields of hierarchy fields of java classes?

Tags: java, field, class-hierarchy

I have a `abstract` class called `ClassA` in my java project. I extends `ClassB` from `ClassA`. Now I want to get all fields of `ClassB`. When I use `ClassB.getDelaredFields()`, this method get only `classB` fields. I can use `ClassA.getDeclaredFields()` but When I have several hierarchical clasess, I cant use it. I want to get all of fields dymcmically. How?

Comment: can you post your code ? so that all can know exact scenario ?

Comment: iterate through all superclasses and add their declared fields until superclass is java.lang.Object

Comment: `Class.getFields()` only get static fields

Comment: pleas refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966629/what-is-the-difference-between-getfields-and-getdeclaredfields-in-java-reflectio)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getFields(), here is example :

```
public class Generic {
    public class SuperA {
        public int f0;
    }

    public class A extends SuperA{
        public int f;
    }

    public class B extends A {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = B.class.getFields();

        for(Field f: fields) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming fields will be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

public variables (from the class and inherited):

```
Field[] fields = yourclass.getFields();
```

every variables non inherited, public and private:

```
Field[] fields2 = yourclass.getDeclaredFields();
```

to get the inherited, protected (what can you do with them ?), iterate through superclass

```
yourclass.getSuperclass()
```