# understand JPA declared attributes of ManagedType

Tags: jpa, attributes, metamodel

JPA ManagedType has

```
public Set<Attribute<? super X, ?>> getAttributes()

public Set<Attribute<X, ?>> getDeclaredAttributes()
```

What are declared attributes? what are not declared attributes? Please explain by example.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/ManagedType.html

Comment: Look at `Class` and `getDeclaredFields`/`getFields`, and you have your answer. Inheritance ...

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is no difference between getConstructor(...) and getDeclaredConstructor(...).

Comment: Addition to @NeilStockton, see also: [What is the difference between getFields and getDeclaredFields in Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966699/2049986).