# Duplicate fields in data classes that extend other (sealed) classes?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

When a data class extends a sealed class containing a non-abstract open val property, the generated child data class contains private fields that duplicate the private fields of the parent class.

```
sealed class Foo(open val field1: String? = null)

data class Bar(override val field1: String? = null) : Foo(field1)
```

Output from `javap -p Foo.class`:

```
public abstract class com.example.Foo {
    private final java.lang.String field1;
    public java.lang.String getField1();
    private com.example.Foo(java.lang.String);
    com.example.Foo(java.lang.String, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);
    public com.example.Foo(java.lang.String, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);
}
```

And `javap -p Bar.class`:

```
public final class com.example.Bar extends com.example.Foo {
    private final java.lang.String field1;
    public java.lang.String getField1();
    public com.example.Bar(java.lang.String);
    public com.example.Bar(java.lang.String, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker);
    public com.example.Bar();
    public final java.lang.String component1();
    public final com.example.Bar copy(java.lang.String);
    public static com.example.Bar copy$default(com.example.Bar, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public int hashCode();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
}
```

The bytecode for `Bar.class` contains its own private field `field1`; the field in the parent class does not appear to be re-used by the child class.

When using frameworks that set fields using reflection, which field will be set? Why is the field in the parent class not re-used by the child class? Is there a way to change the visibility of the field in the parent class to `protected` so it can be re-used by the child class?

Comment: The superclass field is private and private fields cannot be accessed by subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

In that case`Bar` holds the field indeed twice. Two alternatives to have a single field:

```
sealed class Foo(val field1: String?)
data class Bar(private val hiddenField1: String? = null) : Foo(hiddenField1)
```

or

```
sealed class Foo {
    abstract val field1: String?
}
data class Bar(override val field1: String? = null) : Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

The field is not reused because you declared a separate property, which has its own backing field. If you want to reuse the field, change your code to:

```
sealed class Foo(val field1: String? = null)

data class Bar(field1: String? = null) : Foo(field1)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. A data class' primary constructor can only have val or var parameters.

Comment: `data class Bar(field1: String? = null) : Foo(field1)` does not compile. If I change it to a regular class it compiles fine: `class Bar(field1: String? = null) : Foo(field1)`, but then I lose the benefits of the data class.

Answer (score 0):

> When using frameworks that set fields using reflection, which field will be set?

It depends on the class you use. `Foo::class.java.getDeclaredField()` or `Bar::class.java.getDeclaredField()`.

See:

- https://programming.guide/java/accessing-private-fields-of-superclass-through-reflection.html
- [What is the difference between getFields and getDeclaredFields in Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966629)

> Why is the field in the parent class not re-used by the child class?

Why should it? You defined a field-backed property `field1` in both classes. Both fields will exist but `getField1()` method is overridden by child class to return child class' field.

> Is there a way to change the visibility of the field in the parent class to protected so it can be re-used by the child class?

Fields of lateinit properties have the same visibility as the getters. But I'm not sure that's what you want.

How about this?

```
sealed class Foo {
    abstract val field1: String?
}

data class Bar(override val field1: String? = null) : Foo()
```

See discussion here: https://twitter.com/orangy/status/1033067930248867840