# Why I can't access to field class using reflection?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, lombok

I use java spring for my project.
I try to access the property and set it with a specific value using the reflection.

I try to access the name property of User class:

```
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
}
```

Here how I try to access the name field:

```
User newUser = userRepository.get(id); 
User user = accessProp(newUser, User.class, "name", "John");


public <D> D accessProp(Class<D> dest, String fieldName, Object value ){
    Field filed = null;
    var cls = AdminUser.class;

    filed = cls.getField(fieldName);
    filed.set(dest, value);

    return dest;
}
```

But on this  row:

```
 filed = cls.getField(fieldName);
```

I get this error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: name
```

My question is why "name" field not found?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966699/455169

Comment: _why_, though? Do you know what `@Data` does? You already have a `public` getter in the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is why is the "name" field not found?

The `getField` method does not return private fields.  You need to use `getDeclaredField` to get a private field.  But `getDeclaredField` only returns fields for the target class.

So to find and update a private field (in the given class) you need to do something like this:

```
Field field = User.class.getDeclaredField("name");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(userObject, value);
```

(Notice that you also need to use `setAccessible` to allow access to a private field.)

If you wanted to set a named private field in some superclass of a given class, you would need to use `getSuperclass()` to traverse the superclass chain until you found the `Class` that has the field you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the post. In the class, I have @Data annotation, I should create public Set props, any idea how can I use it to access and modify fields value?

Comment: @Michael Use `getMethod("setName", String.class)`, then call `method.invoke("Foo")`. Since the method is public, you don't need to use `getDeclaredMethod` and you don't need to call `setAccessible`.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for this great comment. Can you create a post, please?

Comment: @Michael - what you have done is asked a >different< question in a comment.  Putting an answer to that comment that into an Answer to your original Question wouldn't make much sense.  I expect that's why Andreas didn't do that in the first place.