# Copy pojo fields to another pojo's setters

Tags: java, pojo, dozer

Let's say I have class `A` with public fields `x` and `y`. And let's say I have another pojo class `B` but that uses setters and getters, so it has setX() and setY().

I'd like to use some automatic way to copy from instance of `A` to `B` and back.

With default settings at least, Dozer's

```
   Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
   B b = mapper.map(a, B.class);
```

does not copy the fields correctly.

So is there a simple configuration change that allows me to accomplish the above with Dozer, or another library that would do this for me?

Comment: have you tried using JAXB, ObjectMapper? or you want to user dozer only?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm happy to use any lib that offers "one line conversion" in the above situation.

Comment: you would like to use jaxb, it does annotation based binding so i think it should work for you. checkout http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation and tutorial in the same page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you use:

http://modelmapper.org/

Or take a look at this question:

[Copy all values from fields in one class to another through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667854/copy-all-values-from-fields-in-one-class-to-another-through-reflection)

I'd say that both API's (BeanUtils) and ModelMapper provide one-liners for copy pojos' values to another pojos. Take a look @ this:

http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: Ok, ModelMapper does the job but there's one gotcha, you have to enable field mapping: `mapper.getConfiguration().setFieldMatchingEnabled(true);`.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually a one-liner but this approach doesn't require any libs.

I was testing it using these classes:

```
  private class A {
    public int x;
    public String y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "A [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
  }

  private class B {
    private int x;
    private String y;

    public int getX() {
      return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
      System.out.println("setX");
      this.x = x;
    }

    public String getY() {
      return y;
    }

    public void setY(String y) {
      System.out.println("setY");
      this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "B [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
  }
```

To get public field we can use reflection, as for setters it's better to use bean utils:

```
public static <X, Y> void copyPublicFields(X donor, Y recipient) throws Exception {
    for (Field field : donor.getClass().getFields()) {
      for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(recipient.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (field.getName().equals(descriptor.getName())) {
          descriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(recipient, field.get(donor));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The test:

```
final A a = new A();
a.x = 5;
a.y = "10";
System.out.println(a);
final B b = new B();
copyPublicFields(a, b);
System.out.println(b);
```

And its output is:

```
A [x=5, y=10]
setX
setY
B [x=5, y=10]
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is still looking for,
You could try this using `Gson`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<YourPOJOClass>(){}.getType();
String data = gson.toJson(workingPOJO);
coppiedPOJO = gson.fromJson(data, type);
```