# Create instance of parent from instance of child (for persisting with eBean)

Tags: java, ebean

I have a C parent class and a PC child class which adds temporary metadata.  I want to persist PCs as Cs (discarding the extra data from PCs). Despite casting, eBean outsmarts me and figures out that it really has a PC, not a C.  What is the best way to address this situation?

Some things I've considered:

- Making a "toC" method in PC, which makes a fresh instance of C. This will make updates to C dangerous, though, as they'll require updates to "toC".
- Use reflection in some way to copy all of the fields in PC to a fresh C.
- Tell eBean that it should persist all PCs as Cs. I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution (to my own problem) is to use BeanUtils.copyProperties, which I learned about here: [Copy all values from fields in one class to another through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667854/copy-all-values-from-fields-in-one-class-to-another-through-reflection)