# Apache Bean Utils - Copy Properties to Class With no Setters

Tags: java

To reduce the amount of code written I am trying to use Apache's bean utils to copy properties from one bean to another of a different type with the same fields. However, the destination bean does not have any setters. Ex

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(dest, sourceItem);
```

Since the destination item does not have any setters, it appears that that it's fields are not being set.

Is there another library that can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Note, I am aware that by definition, a class without mutators is not a bean, but I would still like to copy these properties.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263122/copy-object-properties-by-direct-field-access

Comment: Thanks. This does what I'm looking for, but I'm looking for an existing library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using PropertyUtils.copyProperties() ?
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either. The properties of the destination bean are still empty.

Comment: Does the attributes to copy are simple types or map/list ?

Comment: Yes, they are complex objects

Comment: This is from the doc :(
that this method is intended to perform a "shallow copy" of the properties and so complex properties (for example, nested ones) will not be copied.

Comment: Can the use of Cloneable objects can do the job in your case ?

Comment: No, the beans are of different types. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: So you probably have to implement your own reflection library to handle your specific need.

Comment: I'm looking for an existing library.