# How to merge data of one model into another?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am having two models. One is Model A and another is Model B. Both models have getter-setter. But only model A holds value and Model B is totally empty. I want to use Model A and set all those values in model B. How to do that??

In Model A:

```
public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl){this.videoUrl = videoUrl;}
public String getVideoUrl(){return videoUrl;}
```

In Model B:

```
public String getVideoUrl() {
    return videoUrl;
}

public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}
```

In Model A "videoUrl" is already set. I want to set that same "videoUrl" in model B. How to do it??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy all values from fields in one class to another through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667854/copy-all-values-from-fields-in-one-class-to-another-through-reflection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
modelB.setVideoUrl(modelA.getVideoUrl());
```

Comment: this worked perfect for me.. Thank you Shubham..

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `Model B` and get the video URL from `Model A` and set it to `Model B`.

```
ModelA modelA = new ModelA();
modelA.setVideoUrl("YOUR_URL");


ModelB modelB = new ModelB();
modelB.setVideoUrl(modelA.getVideoUrl());
```