# Using MapStruct to convert one POJO to another without having to define that implementation

Tags: java, mapstruct

Suppose I have any given number of POJOs that all share common, identically named properties. Ideally I'd like to avoid a large interface with multiple mappers defined like

```
DtoA fromBToA(DtoB dtoB)
DtoB fromAToB(DtoA dtoA)
DtoC fromAToC(DtoA dtoA)
```

for each of the many POJOs I'll be dealing with.

Is it possible to define an interface which will accept any object and return any object? I tried

```
Object genericMapper(Object object)
```

This obviously doesn't work because it can't access the properties to generate the code.

I suppose since MapStruct documentation states:

> This implementation uses plain Java method invocations for mapping between source and target objects, i.e. no reflection or similar.

what I'm requesting isn't possible, but I just thought I'd get closure or if there are any workarounds available.

Comment: `Object genericMapper(Object object)` won't work because you'd have to at least define the target type you want to get. Also, mapstruct does a lot of compile-time magic so it will need to know which mappers to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use MapStruct for this.

So if for example you define a generic mapper like that:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface GenericMapper {

    <SOURCE, TARGET> TARGET toTarget(SOURCE source);
    
}
```

or like that:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface GenericMapper<SOURCE, TARGET> {

    TARGET toTarget(SOURCE source);
    
}
```

as soon as you try to build the project, you will get an error:

**GenericMapper.java: Can't generate mapping method for a generic type variable source.**

As an alternative solution, you can use [BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

see also:
[Copy all values from fields in one class to another through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667854/copy-all-values-from-fields-in-one-class-to-another-through-reflection)