# Is using DTO's obsolete with JPA and JSF

Tags: jpa, jsf, design-patterns

I am bit confused how to setup a project correctly regarding data flow between Backend (JPA) and Frontend (JSF)

In my old schooltime I learned using DAO's (Repository, Service) and DTO's, but actually I dont see any need of using DTO's anymore. Thats why I am asking here for consulting me howto setup the general framework using JPA and JSF.

I have the following situation:

An Entity Car:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "cars")
    public class Car {

        @Id
        @Size(min = 1)
        private String identifier;
```

a Repository with basic functionality accessing the DB:

```
@Stateless
public class CarRepository implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Car> getAllCars(){
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("Select c from Car c");
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

a managed bean with sessionscope:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "carlistbean")
@SessionScoped
public class CarListBean implements Serializable {

private List<Car> cars= new ArrayList();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        cars = carRepository.getAllCars();
    }
```

In my facelet I am referencing the cars:

```
<h:dataTable value = "#{carlistbean.cars}" var = "car"
```

As you can see I am skipping the DTO part (for my understanding), but in the other way I am "mixing" Beanvalidation and JPA definitions in the Entity.

My Car Entity has a bidirectional relation to another entity Manufacturer, which I can access using the getter method. So no need to create a composite DTO for that ?

Is this bad, acceptable, good design ? How would you structure the data flow in 2019 ?

Comment: How will you show the data which is come from two tables/two entity into same datatable? It is depend on your usage.

Comment: Good question. Thanks for helping. I have a bidirectional Relation defined @oneToMany and ManyToOne. So I could access the other entity directly.

Comment: If you try to ORM (mapping) for UI / client data, your ORM might be complex. For my experience, Data model is different with UI display / client data.

Comment: In many cases the plain JPA ORM mapping is usable in UI's too. So use it when you can, add/create additional classes (or just transient fields when needed). Works for me in most cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DTO in JSF + Spring + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722036/how-to-use-dto-in-jsf-spring-hibernate)

Comment: Please read [why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

Following the JSF and Java EE experts advises like Bauke Scholtz [How to use DTO in JSF + Spring + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722036/how-to-use-dto-in-jsf-spring-hibernate/5722956#5722956) and Adam Bien [How evil are Data Transfer Objects](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_evil_are_actually_data) it is better to not use DTO objects.