# java object to object mapping appropriate for android

Tags: android

Which tool is able to map one object to another object in Android?

I found this topic [any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping)

There are many tools for java, I tried Orika and ModelMapper but without any success. java.beans miss for ModelMapper. Orika has problems with slf4j-logging.