# Hiding data objects structure and fields to WebServices clients

Tags: java, web-services, api, design-patterns

We have a classic order management application developed in Java on a Controller / Service / DAO architecture. Data objects are POJOs representing the data in the database. Basically we have 1 class which maps 1 table in the database but we don't use any ORM or entity mechanism These data objects are passed between all layers to create/modify/get orders through Web GUI.
This application also has a WebService layer which allow external systems to manage those orders through SOAP. The WebService layer relies on the Service layer to make sure same logic is used between WebService and GUI.

We try to make the WebServices API as stable as possible but, as we are currently using our data objects as parameters of our WebService methods, that API is likely to change frequently (at least each time we had or modify any field in the database). Moreover, we would like to hide some complexity of the database structure to WebService clients. For example, the database contains multiple fields which we would like to hide from the clients.

Concrete question(s):

- What kind of design pattern is commonly used to hide database
  structure and fields through client API?
- Are there any good practices to handle "mappings" between public
  methods parameters and internal data objets?
- Is the Data Transfer Object the answer to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be passing data objects across process boundaries. It makes your application brittle and guarantees a lot of rework every time you make a schema change. My suggestion is this:

-The data access layer should be just that: dealing with Creating, Reading, Updating and Deleting database objects. Users of the DAL must know how the database works in order to use it.

ex (in psuedo-code):

```
Person = {
PERSON_ID:'1234567jksjgkhsduw0909wueioksgt',
FIRST_NAME:'CHRIS',
LAST_NAME:'MCCALL',
TITLE:'',
GENDER:'M',
LAST_NAME_SUFFIX:null,
Addresses = [{ADDRESS_ID:1234,...}]
}
```

etc
-The service layer transforms database schema to hide complexity and cast opinions on what's really useful to the developer trying to make apps with this data

ex:

```
Person = {
name:'Chris McCall',
primary_address:'123 Main St',
secondary_address:null
}
```

You may decide to include the ID or not. You may decide to change the case on the field names, and you might project the data into a form that makes more sense to the app developer, and is more stable than your database schema. Maybe you leave a bunch of stuff out, so there's less data going over the wire. Stuff like that.

Your DBAs are tasked with making a database that performs well and maximizes storage via normalization. That's a different goal than the service layer, which does not expect the results of its calls to be persisted.

Different architectures have differentnames for the View Model (which is what I call it). DTO is another name.

Comment: I know separating layers and minimizing dependencies is a good pattern, but isn't it a lot of more work to have two separate domain models.

Comment: Yes, it is more work, but only for you, not all the clients that depend on the output of your service. For them it's far less work, and they don't have to understand your data model to use your results. Data models have totally different requirements, for persistent storage and recall. Domain models conceptualize the problem into something clients can understand. It's the same thing as saying making a UI instead of just giving SQL access is "more work".

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. It makes me realized that we really need a new set of classes so that the domain model can change without changing the public API. Googling with that in mind, I found what I was really looking for and I was able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

> We try to make the WebServices API as stable as possible but, as the
>   our data objects are used as parameters of our WebService methods,
>   that API is likely to change frequently

You are already in the wrong way. Web Services is about interroperability and integration in a platform-agnostic way.
All objects passed to Web Services should be "data-holders" and should have nothing to do with your business logic. You should have converters to map these "data-holders" to the actual classes you need for your application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I totally agree that it's a problem and that's one point of my question. What are these "data-holders" and "converters"? What design pattern should we implement as we'll have a lot of them as the application will grow?

Answer (score -2):

Answering my own question:

We are clearly facing the problem of exposing structured data to a public API. These data are coming from the domain model (data objets) manage internally but the domain model MUST NOT been exposed through the public API directly.

Instead, another set of classes, often called Data Transfer Objects (DTO) or View Models must be created and maintained to be used as input/ouput parameters of the public API. With such DTO, the domain model can change without modifying the public API and the public API can be change in a very well controlled way.

Some mappings (also called bindings), must be maintained in the application between the domain model and DTO. Often in both directions. A great list of Java mapper/binder libraries can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956/946487)

Comment: downvoted for restating my answer and then accepting it as correct. Come on, man