# Translating values contained in a javax Response type to a list to be formatted into a json array

Tags: java, arrays, json

So my question might be a bit silly to some of you, but I am querying for some data that must be returned as a Response, I then have to use parts of that data in the front end of my application to graph it using AngularJS and nvD3 charts. To correctly format the data for the graphing tool, I must translate this data into the correct json format. I could find no direct way to pull the numbers i needed out of the returned Response. I need to take just the values I need and translate them into a list to be then parsed into a json array. The following is my work around for this and it works, giving me the list I am looking for...

```
if (tableState.getIdentifier().getProperty().equals("backupSize")){
        Response test4 = timeSeriesQuery.queryData("backup.data.size,", "", "1y-ago", "25", "desc");
        String test5 = test4.getEntity().toString();
        int test6 = test5.indexOf("value");
        int charIndexStart = test6 + 9;
        int charIndexEnd = test5.indexOf(",", test6);
        String test7 = test5.substring(charIndexStart, charIndexEnd);
        int charIndexStart2 = test5.indexOf(",", charIndexEnd);
        int charIndexEnd2 = test5.indexOf(",", charIndexStart2 + 2);
        String test9 = test5.substring(charIndexStart2 + 1, charIndexEnd2);
        long test8 = Long.parseLong(test7);
        long test10 = Long.parseLong(test9);
        List<Long> graphs = new ArrayList<>();
        graphs.add(test8);
        graphs.add(test10);
        List<List<Long>> graphs2 = new ArrayList<List<Long>>();
        graphs2.add(graphs);
        for(int i=1, charEnd = charIndexEnd2; i<24; i++){
            int nextCharStart = test5.indexOf("}", charEnd) + 2;
            int nextCharEnd = test5.indexOf(",", nextCharStart);
            String test11 = test5.substring(nextCharStart + 1, nextCharEnd);
            int nextCharStart2 = test5.indexOf(",", nextCharEnd) + 1;
            int nextCharEnd2 = test5.indexOf(",", nextCharStart2 + 2);
            String test13 = test5.substring(nextCharStart2, nextCharEnd2);
            long test12 = Long.parseLong(test11);
            long test14 = Long.parseLong(test13);
            List<Long> graphs3 = new ArrayList<>();
            graphs3.add(test12);
            graphs3.add(test14);
            graphs2.add(graphs3);
            charEnd = test5.indexOf("}", nextCharEnd2);
        } return graphs2;
```

here is the result of test5:

xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.timeseries.datapoints.queryresponse.DatapointsResponse@2be02a0c[start=, end=, tags={xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.timeseries.datapoints.queryresponse.Tag@1600cd19[name=backup.data.size, results={xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.timeseries.datapoints.queryresponse.Results@2b8a61bd[groups={xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.timeseries.datapoints.queryresponse.Group@61540dbc[name=type, type=number]}, attributes=xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.util.map.Map@4b4eebd0[], values={{1487620485896,973956,3},{1487620454999,973806,3},{1487620424690,956617,3},{1487620397181,938677,3},{1487620368825,934494,3},{1487620339219,926125,3},{1487620309050,917753,3},{1487620279239,909384,3},{1487620251381,872864,3},{1487620222724,846518,3},{1487620196441,832150,3},{1487620168141,819563,3},{1487620142079,787264,3},{1487620115827,787264,3},{1487620091991,787264,3},{1487620067230,787264,3},{1487620042333,787264,3},{1487620018508,787264,3},{1487619994967,787264,3},{1487619973549,778740,3},{1487619950069,770205,3},{1487619926850,749106,3},{1487619902486,740729,3},{1487619877298,728184,3},{1487619851449,719666,3}}]}, stats=xxx.xx.xxxxxx.entity.timeseries.datapoints.queryresponse.Stats@5bb68fa5[rawCount=25]]}]

and the returned list:

[[1487620485896, 973956], [1487620454999, 973806], [1487620424690, 956617], [1487620397181, 938677], [1487620368825, 934494], [1487620339219, 926125], [1487620309050, 917753], [1487620279239, 909384], [1487620251381, 872864], [1487620222724, 846518], [1487620196441, 832150], [1487620168141, 819563], [1487620142079, 787264], [1487620115827, 787264], [1487620091991, 787264], [1487620067230, 787264], [1487620042333, 787264], [1487620018508, 787264], [1487619994967, 787264], [1487619973549, 778740], [1487619950069, 770205], [1487619926850, 749106], [1487619902486, 740729], [1487619877298, 728184]]

I can then take this and shove it into a json (at least i think so! haven't gotten that far). But this code seems ridiculous, brittle, and not the right way to go about this.

Does anyone have a better way of pulling datapoints out of a response and translating them into a json array or at least a nested list?

Thank you to anyone who read and please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Is this data coming from a database?

Comment: yes it is @Steven

Comment: ok, then you need to use resultset, I will develop an answer

Answer (score 0):

When we want just a few values from a query the best way to retrieve them is doing the query with `resultSet` and using it's powerful metadata:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696782/retrieve-column-names-from-java-sql-resultset)

So you take the columns you need by using the metadata properties and then the best you can do is use a DTO object to store each row [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117403/dto-pattern-best-way-to-copy-properties-between-two-objects) to learn a bit more about DTOs

So, basically the idea is that you build an object from the data you've retrieved or just the one you need at that moment from the database and you can use the common getters and setters to access all the fields

However, when collecting data you're normally going to be using loops as you need to iterate over the resultSet values asking for the name of the column and keeping it's value if it coincides.

Hope it helps