# Mapping validation property paths using bean mappers like ModelMapper, Orika or Dozer

Tags: validation, dto, dozer, modelmapper, orika

Given that a bean mapper is used to map a Business Modell of into a DTO model and vice versa:
Which one do provide easy ways to convert property paths?

Lets say my business logic reports that *"person.street.number"* is mandatory and now I want tell the client this in the correct way, i.e. as *"personDto.streetnumber"*?

I'm pretty sure every bean mapper has this knowledge, but which one provide easy ways to access this knowledge?

Based [on this excellent list of bean mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956) and further reading on their websites if found ModelMapper and Orika to look pretty attractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelMapper seems to offer good ways to access this information. Depending on the configuration, most specifically the `MatchingStrategy`, ModelMapper will automatically convert values from source paths to destination paths so long as they match.

To access this information one can use `ModelMapper.getTypeMap` and `TypeMap.getMappings`.