# Simple object-to-object mapper without xml?

Tags: java, mapping

I'm looking for an object-to-object mapper that works without XML configurations. It should be possible to transform any simple type as well as nested lists from one object to a completely different object.

Like:

```
class IncomingDTO {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    List<Customer> customers;
}

class Customer {
    Address address;
}


class ResultDTO {
    String name; //should be a combination of firstname+lastname
    List<Address> addresses; //which might come from    
}
```

I'm looking for a way to not having iterate through each of the objects and copy every single entry manually. Maybe there is a library that I can give some kind of mapping configuration that does the rest for me?

Comment: Jackson can easily map one implementation of a POJO interface to another.  Two lines of code and really fast.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to do this in your Java code if possible. I'm not sure why there's a benefit to having some declaration-based solution when a code-based solution is more likely easier to read and more extensible.

If you need a framework to do this, perhaps [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) is of use. It provides a means of identifying [mappings using annotations](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html) (as well as XML)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at apache commons beanutils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils
```

has methods to help you like

```
public static void copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)
```

which

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for
>   all cases where the property names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Orika,

Orika is a Java Bean mapping framework that recursively copies (among other capabilities) data from one object to another. It can be very useful when developing multi-layered applications.

[Orika on GitHub](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika)