# Java Reflection: Invoking Setter and Getter method for collection type Object

Tags: java, reflection, mapping

I have two different packages of User define Objects.....

```
1) ws.lender.dto (all Objects exists in this package are source side).
2) copl.com.dto (all Objects exists in this package are destination side).
```

Objects hierarchy and Objects name different in both side. I wan to
 copy source side object to destination side object field by field or
 via getter and setter using Reflection.

For Example

Source side Objects

```
   package ws.lender.dto;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "CustomerAddresses", propOrder = {
        "previousAddresses"
    })
    public class CustomerAddresses {

        protected PreviousAddresses previousAddresses;

        public PreviousAddresses getPreviousAddresses() {
            return previousAddresses;
        }

        public void setPreviousAddresses(PreviousAddresses value) {
            this.previousAddresses = value;
        }

    }


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PreviousAddresses", propOrder = {
    "previousAddress"
})
public class PreviousAddresses {

    @XmlElement(name = "PreviousAddress", required = true)
    protected List<PreviousAddress> previousAddress;

    public List<PreviousAddress> getPreviousAddress() {
        if (previousAddress == null) {
            previousAddress = new ArrayList<PreviousAddress>();
        }
        return this.previousAddress;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PreviousAddress", propOrder = {

    "streetNo",
    "streetName"
})
public class PreviousAddress {

    @XmlElement(name = "StreetNo", required = true)
    protected String streetNo;
    @XmlElement(name = "StreetName", required = true)
    protected String streetName;

    public String getStreetNo() {
        return streetNo;
    }
    public void setStreetNo(String value) {
        this.streetNo = value;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String value) {
        this.streetName = value;
    }
}
```

Destination side Objects

```
package copl.com.dto;

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable
{
private Set<CustomerAddress> customerAddresses;

   public Set<CustomerAddress> getCustomerAddresses()
    {
        return customerAddresses;
    }

        public void setCustomerAddresses(Set<CustomerAddress> customerAddresses)
    {
        this.customerAddresses = customerAddresses;
    }
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class CustomerAddress implements java.io.Serializable
{   
    private String unitNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String streetNumber;

   public String getUnitNumber()
    {
        return unitNumber;
    }   
        public void setUnitNumber(String unitNumber)
    {
        this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
    }
        public String getStreetName()
    {
        return streetName;
    }
       public String getStreetNumber()
    {
        return streetNumber;
    }
        public void setStreetName(String streetName)
    {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetNumber(String streetNumber)
    {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer I need help from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have studied many objects mapping frameworks for this assignments like

- [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html)
- [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/)
- [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)
- [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/)
- [Commons-BeanUtils](http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/beanutils)

Finally I choose the  [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html) framework to complete that above Objects to Objects mapping. We can do the that mapping via other mapper framework, but I was like  [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html) framework because this framework very easy to use for mapping Objects to Objects.

I will explain step by step.

**1. Create the Objects of Source side Object and Destination side Object.**

like this..

> ```
>     Customer destination = new Customer();
>     CustomerAddresses source = new CustomerAddresses();
>     source = filledCustomerAddressesObject();
> ```

**2. Constructing the DefaultMapperFactory**

```
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
```

**3. Mapping fields**

```
    ClassMapBuilder<CustomerAddresses, Customer> builder;
    
    builder= mapperFactory.classMap(CustomerAddresses.class, Customer.class).constructorA();

    builder.field("previousAddresses.previousAddress{streetNo}","customerAddresses{streetNumber}");
    builder.field("previousAddresses.previousAddress{streetName}","customerAddresses{streetName}");
    
    builder.register();

    BoundMapperFacade<CustomerAddresses, Customer> boundMapper;
    
    boundMapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(CustomerAddresses.class, Customer.class);
    
    destination = boundMapper.map(source, destination);
```

Its work fine Cheers

Answer (score 8):

I think you could use [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) to mapping between POJO's that has different attribute names.

But your scenario is complex, because you want to convert `ws.lender.dto.CustomerAddresses` to `copl.com.dto.Customer`, and this implies to convert a `List<ws.lender.dto.PreviousAddress>` contained into  a `ws.lender.dto.PreviousAddresses` object, to a `Set<copl.com.dto.CustomerAddress>` contained into a `copl.com.dto.Customer` object.

So, I will explain step by step.

### 1. Convert from `ws.lender.dto.PreviousAddress` to `copl.com.dto.CustomerAddress`

To do this conversion you need an interface (MapStruct will create an instance for this) responsible for mapping from source object to destination object:

```
import ws.lender.dto.PreviousAddress;
import copl.com.dto.CustomerAddress;

@Mapper
public interface CustomerAddressesMapper{

    CustomerAddressesMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CustomerAddressesMapper.class );

    @Mappings(@Mapping(source = "streetNo", target = "streetNumber")
    CustomerAddress previousToCustomerObject(PreviousAddress address);
}
```

This interface will map a `PreviousAddress` object to a `CustomerAddress` considering that `streetNo` attribute has to be mapped to `streetNumber`. There is no mapping for `unitNumber` attribute cause there is no source for it.

### 2. Convert a `List<ws.lender.dto.PreviousAddress>` to `Set<copl.com.dto.CustomerAddress>`

Now you have to add another mapping method to existing `CustomerAddressesMapper` interface:

```
Set<CustomerAddress> previousToCustomerSet(List<PreviousAddress> addresses);
```

This method will use the former `previousToCustomerObject` to convert every element of source list to destination set.

### 3. Convert from `ws.lender.dto.CustomerAddresses` to `copl.com.dto.Customer`

Finally, you need to add the last mapping method to `CustomerAddressesMapper` interface:

```
@Mappings(@Mapping(source = "previousAddresses.previousAddress", target = "customerAddresses")
Customer customerAddrsToCustomerObject(CustomerAddresses addresses);
```

This is the where you map an origin object, converting `previousAddresses.previousAddress` attribute to `customerAddresses` attribute, using former methods.

### 4. Using the mapper

To use the mapper you have to write some code as following:

```
CustomerAddressesMapper mapper = CustomerAddressesMapper.INSTANCE;
CustomerAddresses origin = //Retrieve it from anywhere
Customer dest = mapper.customerAddrsToCustomerObject(origin);
```

### 5. Setup

MapStruct is a source code generator, so you need to properly configure your `pom.xml` to include MapStruct dependency and to invoke this code generation. You can see how to do this [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/#section-setup)

Well I don't build and run this code, but this is the way to do it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for spend the time to this question, I have tried to use the above but not succeeded, then I have moved to orika mapper framework and I have done job. but finally I decided it to award the bounty to you.

Comment: @Z.I.J, out of interest, what specific issues did you run into? Would be glad to learn more about the details, maybe there is something we can improve in MapStruct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Object Mapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) better for casting or copying. The object to other classes in other packages you can add some property value like

> **senderClass** and **rvcClass**

Later you can read those properties and proceed for converting the class. Probably you already have mapping ready for sender class against receiver class.

Comment: I think Object Mapper is used for JSON to Object or Object to JSON.

Comment: Please have a look it this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need a way to copy all like-named properties from one object to another.  Like-named properties would be cases in which the source object has a method called something like getPropertyName() and the destination object has one called setPropertyName().

If this is right, then you want to use the copyProperties method of the BeanUtils class from the Apache Commons library.  Documentation is [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).

Now, in your example, you have some corresponding properties that are not like-named, such as StreetNumber and StreetNo.  I'm afraid there's no easy way to handle that sort of thing automatically through reflection; you would need to define the mappings between source and target properties yourself, perhaps by defining a helper class to do the copying.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.