# Mapper code generation

Tags: java, mapping, datamapper

There are many mapper tools available for pojo and DTO. Check the link: [any tool for java object to object mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping) 
But is there any tool generates the DAO, Service classes automatically?

Dozer Sample:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>yourpackage.SourceClassName</class-a>
  <class-b>yourpackage.DestinationClassName</class-b>
    <field>
      <A>yourSourceFieldName</A>
      <B>yourDestinationFieldName</B>
    </field>
</mapping>

SourceClassName sourceObject = ...
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
DestinationObject destObject =
    mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationClassName.class);
assertTrue(destObject.getYourDestinationFieldName().equals(sourceObject.getYourSourceFieldName));
```

Here the xml configuration is fine, but can I skip the code part and just specify the POJO-DTO configuration or POJO-DTO along-with filter configuration. And some tool should be able to automatically generate intermediate translation code in the form of DAO and Service classes. Are there any such tools available?

Answer (score 0):

Mybe late, I develop an annotation processor called [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife) recently, it support generate DTO from any class. You need config by annotation. But you don't need change the original class. This library support configuring on a separate class. Of course you can choose which property you want and which you not need. And you can add new property by the static method in the config class. The most power feature of this library is it support automatically convert a object property to the DTO version. for example

```
class Pojo1 {
    String a;
    Pojo b;
}

class Pojo2 {
    Pojo1 a;
    List<Pojo1> b;
    Map<List<Pojo1>>[] c;
}

@ViewOf(value = Pojo1.class, includePattern = ".*", excludes={Pojo1Meta.b})
class ConfigureOfPojo2 {}

@ViewOf(value = Pojo2.class, includePattern = ".*")
class ConfigureOfPojo2 {
    // convert b to dto version
    @OverrideViewProperty(Pojo2Meta.b)
    private List<Pojo1View> b;
    // convert c to dto version
    @OverrideViewProperty(Pojo2Meta.c)
    private Map<List<Pojo1View>>[] c;
}
```

will generate

```
// meta class, you can use it to reference the property name in a safe way.
class Pojo1Meta {
    public final String a = "a";
    public final String b = "b";
}

// generated DTO class. The actual one will be more complicate, there are many other method.
class Pojo1View {
    private String a;
    public Pojo1View read(Pojo1 source) { ... }
    ... getters and setters ...
}

class Pojo2Meta {
    public final String a = "a";
    public final String b = "b";
    public final String c = "c";
}

class Pojo2View {
    private String a;
    private List<Pojo1View> b;
    private Map<List<Pojo1View>>[] c;
    public Pojo1View read(Pojo2 source) { ... }
    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

The interest things here is you can safely use the class not exist yet in the source. Although the compiler may complain, all will be ok after compiled. Because all the extra class will be automatically generated just before compiled.
A better approach may be to compile step by step, first add @ViewOf annotations, and then compile, so that all the classes that need to be used later are generated. Compile again after the configuration is complete. The advantage of this is that the IDE will not have grammatical error prompts, and can make better use of the IDE's auto-complete function.

To use the DTO object in the code, just call static read method like this

```
Pojo2 source = ...
Pojo2View dto = Pojo2View.read(source);
List<Pojo2> listSource = ...
List<Pojo2View> dtoList = Pojo2View.read(listSource)
Map<String, Pojo2> mapSource = ...
List<Pojo2View> dtoMap = Pojo2View.read(mapSource)
```

No reflect, no magic. All logical you can check in the generated class.