# save values from DTO object to entity in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dto

in my hibernate project i use getters and setters to save data. In every time i need to use get method and set method for each variable to save.
the question is that is there any convenient way to convert DTO to entity class?
reagrds

Comment: You could use a library to map java beans Take a look this answer you can find some  intersting libraries for such thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956/4751165

Comment: Possible duplicate of [any tool for java object to object mapping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

An entity view example could look like this

```
@EntityView(Person.class)
interface PersonDto {
  @Mapping("CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)")
  String getName();
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
List<PersonDto> dtos = entityViewManager.applySetting(
  EntityViewSetting.create(PersonDto.class),
  criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, Person.class)
).getResultList();
```