# Composing two binary objects

Tags: java, ignite

I have two `BinaryObject`s:

```
BinaryObject bo1;
BinaryObject bo2;
```

Is there a way to compose this two binary objects. I mean to add all fields from `bo1` to `bo2` which does not exist in `bo2`? I tried

```
bo1.toBuilder();
bo2.toBuilder();
```

But I didn't find a way to compose these builders into one I need. The thing is I don't know fields in these objects.

Actually I have cache with `BinaryObject`s as values. I'm writing `StreamReceiver` to update its values the way I specified above. That way I have to implement the following method:

```
@Override
public void receive(IgniteCache<String, BinaryObject> cache, Collection<Map.Entry<String, BinaryObject>> entries) throws IgniteException {
    BinaryObject objOld = cache.get(entry.getKey());      
    BinaryObjectBuilder previous = objOld.toBuilder();
    BinaryObject objNew = entry.getValue();
    BinaryObjectBuilder current = objNew.toBuilder();
    //...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping

Comment: @StanislavL Dont see how it relates to my problem Can u expand a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-liner for this. But you can create a builder from the object you're merging to, and use `BinaryObject.type().fieldNames()` on the second object to get list of fields it contains. Then iterate through these fields and append values to builder.