# Ignoring a JPA property if its not present in json response and converting if its present in json

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I get a Json response from upstream response as shown below.

```
{
    "fieldone": {
    "header": {
    "requestId": "1234",
    "applicationName": "office",
    "status": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "lineLevel": [{
    "ou": "1025854560",
    "status": "REJECT"
    }]
    }
}
```

LineLevel field may or  may not be part of JSON response every time.we may get or may not.when we were not getting it it was causing issue .to resolve it I have tried with @jsonIgnore at property level but its ignoring the field when we get that particular field as part of response.

Tried @JsonIgnoreProperties at class level but its causing issue when respective proeprty is not present in Json response

can any provide any pointers in resolving it.Irrespective of whether LineLevel property is present or not in Json response I should be go ahead with my process

Comment: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) which will ignore null values

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
LineLevel lineLevel
```

That will convert this field, only when it's not null.

You can get examples [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in mind, I strongly encourage you to use different classes for the persistence entity and for mapping the JSON response coming the from the upstream server.

If the boilerplate code of mapping one object to another is a concern, use [mapping frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956/1426227) such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).