# Java: Copy properties from bean to an another one

Tags: java

I've these two classes:

```
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    private String id;
    private List<Parameter> parameters;
}

public class ConfigurationUpdateForm {

    @NotEmpty private String id;

    @NotEmpty @Valid private Collection<ConfigurationParameterForm> parameters;
}
```

I need to copy all properties from an `ConfigurationUpdateForm` object to an `ServiceConfiguration` object:

```
ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
try {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(serviceConfiguration, configurationForm);
} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it doesn't copy `parameters` collection correctly.

What's failing is after `copyProperties`, `destinationbean.parameters` contains a list of `ParameterTypeForm` instead of a list of `Parameter`...

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean doesn't copy correctly? what is the error? perhaps it is because the two variables arenot defined the same?

Comment: Use another library, like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). There is a list of [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping) solutions .

Comment: After `copyProperties`, `destinationbean.parameters` contains a list of `ParameterTypeForm` instead of a list of `Parameter`...

Answer (score 0):

`BeanUtils.copyProperties(serviceConfiguration, configurationForm)` will just copy all the bean properties of one class to the other for all cases where the name is the same.

As both classes contain the `parameters` property, `BeanUtils` will just copy the value.

And that is exactly what is happening in your result, suddenly the parameters inside `ServiceConfiguration` contains a list of `ConfigurationParameterForm` objects.

This is because the copying is only being done one level deep and also because at runtime nothing is preventing a List to contain objects of different classes than those you specified in the declaration.

In example:

```
public class Dog {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a dog";
    }
}

public class Cat {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I'm a cat";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
    dogs.add(new Dog());

    addCat(dogs);

    System.out.println(dogs);
}

public static void addCat(List cats) {
    cats.add(new Cat());
}
```

Running the above code will result in:
`[I'm a dog, I'm a cat]`

A possible solution would be to add your own mapping method that will map from one class to the other using getters and setters, but you will also need a mapping from: `ConfigurationParameterForm` to `Parameter`