# How to transform entities extending a generic class to another entity extending another generic class

Tags: java, oop

I'm developing a service oriented platform for retrieving, creating and updating entities from DB.
The point here is that every single java entity extends `AbstractEntity`, so for example, I have,

```
MyCar extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable
```

This `AbstractEntity` has common fields (such as id or audit ones).
So I have already developed a `GenericReadService` that, receiving a **classname** and a **parameterMap**, can read any entity and creates a `EntityActionResult<T>` including a `List<T extends AbstractEntity>`.

My problem comes when trying to transform that `T` type into something like `<K extends GenericDTO>`, as the client asking doesn't know `AbstractEntity` (obvious) but only `GenericDTO`. Doing this for safety and modularization.

So, now, I'm stuck on transforming the `ListResponse<T>` to a `ReturnList<K extends GenericDTO>`, as I don't find the way for knowing which `K` class should apply for each `T`.

This is what I actually have written:

```
    private GenericEntityActionResult transform (EntityActionResult result) {
        AsnGenericEntityActionResult r = new AsnGenericEntityActionResult();
        if (result.getCode() == EntityActionResult.Code.ENTITY || result.getCode() == EntityActionResult.Code.ENTITY_LIST ) {
            r.setCode(AsnGenericEntityActionResult.Code.OK);
            List <? extends GenericDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (result.getEntity() != null) {
                //transform this entity into DTO
                //<b>SOMETHING LIKE list.add(result.getEntity());</b>
            } else if (result.getList() != null && !result.getList().isEmpty()) {
                for (AbstractEntity a:result.getList()) {
                    //transform this entity into DTO
                    //<b>SOMETHING LIKE list.add(result.getEntity());</b>
                    //list.add(result.getEntity());
                }
            }
            r.setList(list);
        }
        return r;
```

I´m obviously stuck on the SOMETHING LIKE, but can't find a proper way of doing so.

I thought about creating a `abstract <T extends GenericDTO> transformToDTO()` method on `AbstractEntity`, but can't do it since there are  **lots** (and i mean hundreds) of Entities extending `AbstractEntity` and this client-service approach is a new development for some Entities, not the whole system.

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Do you have to do the transformation for all (hundreds) of Entities or only for some?

Comment: Only for some. May be all of them in the future, but not thinking about that at the moment.

Comment: Bean Introspection ?

Comment: Could you provide an example of that, Victor? I'm not quite sure of understanding you, but if I have... how would i know which K extending GenericDTO applies to each T extending AbstractEntity?

Comment: Well, how about defining that method that you wanted - but not as abstract, but with a default implementation (maybe throwing an exception, or returning an empty `Optional`), and overriding it only in the entities you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [Java Introspection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) or some more robust library on top of this API like [apache commons beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) or even more powerful bean mapping library like Dozer or something newer [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432764/any-tool-for-java-object-to-object-mapping)

Following example demonstrating the basic technique, only raw introspection and reflection with two compatible POJO beans.

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


class Tranformation {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyCar car = new MyCar();
        car.setId("id01");
        car.setName("Komodo");
        car.setMadeIn("Jakarta");

        CarDTO dto = toDto(CarDTO.class, car);

        System.out.println(dto);

    }

    public <E extends AbstractEntity, D extends GenericDTO> D toDto(Class<D> dtoClass, E entity) {
        if (null == entity) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Entity can not be null");
        }
        try {
            final D ret = dtoClass.newInstance();

            BeanInfo dtoBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(dtoClass);

            final Map<String, PropertyDescriptor> mapping = Arrays.stream(dtoBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(PropertyDescriptor::getName, Function.identity()));

            final BeanInfo entityBeanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(entity.getClass());

            Arrays.stream(entityBeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()).forEach(src -> {
                if (!"class".equals(src.getName())) {
                    PropertyDescriptor dst = mapping.get(src.getName());
                    if (null != dst) {
                        try {
                            dst.getWriteMethod().invoke(ret, src.getReadMethod().invoke(entity, null));
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            return ret;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IntrospectionException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static class GenericDTO {
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    public static class CarDTO extends GenericDTO {
        private String madeIn;

        public String getMadeIn() {
            return madeIn;
        }

        public void setMadeIn(String madeIn) {
            this.madeIn = madeIn;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("CarDTO [id=%s, name=%s, madeIn=%s]", getId(), getName(), madeIn);
        }

    }

    public static class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 70377433289079231L;
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static class MyCar extends AbstractEntity {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8702011501211036271L;
        private String madeIn;

        public String getMadeIn() {
            return madeIn;
        }

        public void setMadeIn(String madeIn) {
            this.madeIn = madeIn;
        }

    }

}
```

Outputs:

```
CarDTO [id=id01, name=Komodo, madeIn=Jakarta]
```

Comment: Well this seems exactly what i was looking for. Let me try it first, but thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: I think I will finally opt between ModelMapper and MapStruct, but many thanks for the guidance, I wasn't aware all these frameworks did exist at all!