# How can i fix output of Classes with relationship using Dtos in spring boot?

Tags: java, class, resources, dto

my class

```
public class Teacher
```

has ManyToMany relationship with Students :

```
public class Student
```

when i return teachers i want only their student ids , instead of full information about their students.

we have two Dtos (DataTransferObject) : StudentDto and TeacherDto with some variables.

what can i do to solve this problem?

I want Students as well to return only names or ids of Teachers. instead they return full dto list of teachers.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TeacherDto` you shouldn't have list of `StudentDto`s but rather list of `Integer` (if `Integer` is type of id). Than you should implement some mapping logic, for example in the constructor, like this:

```
public class TeacherDto {
    private final Set<Integer> studentIds;

    public TeacherDto(Teacher teacher) {
        this.studentIds = teacher.getStudents().stream()
                .map(Student::getId)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public Set<Integer> getStudentIds() {
        return studentIds;
    }
}
```

If you have many different DTOs, there is [a lot of libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432956/9353852) which help you automate mapping between them.